# Construct a list given two different lists — a list of elements and a list of indices of those elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two separate lists, say:

```
L1={{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}
L2={A12,A13,A23}
```

How can I construct a single matrix A with values 
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & A12 & A13 \\
  0 & 0 & A23   \\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

I understand that one can do loop:

```
A=ConstArray[0,{3,3}];
For[i=1, i<= Length @ L1, i++,
    A[[L1[[i,1]],L1[[i,2]]] = L2[[i]]
    ]
```

Still, this construction does not seem general, especially if working with multidimensional (multiply nested) lists. Is there a way to formalise this algorithm?
Furthermore, I am using "For" loop which is not very natural for Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following approach should be pretty general:

```
Normal @ SparseArray[L1 -> L2, {3, 3}, 0]

(* Out: {{0, A12, A13}, {0, 0, A23}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for!